# Methods for detecting nonlinear relationships among variables

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression

I believe that some of my independent variables vary nonlinearly with my dependent variable. I know of a couple of ways to determine the possible type of function, but I'm wondering other methods, and about their effectiveness.

What I know:
1) Including a power of the variable in the regression. If I think $x_i$ varies quadratically with $y$, I can include $x_{i}^{2}$ as another variable to see if it is significant. This seems to rely on previous theory, and checks for only that specific power of the variable. (Is this correct?)

2) Looking at a plot of $x_{i}$ vs. residuals of a fit line. This doesn't seem to rely on previous theory and can show many relationships. This seems to be better than (1), but I have seen $AGE^2$ used in a few papers, why not just look at a residual plot in case the relationship isn't in fact quadratic?

What other methods are there, and which one should be used?

Comment: A more refined approach is offered by the partial residual plot. Perhaps this will be of help to you. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_residual_plot

Comment: @JohnK Thank you. So as long as my independent variables aren't highly collinear, it would be more beneficial to use the partial residual plots because they take into account the correlation between the independent variables?

Comment: They take into account which variables are in the model, yes. What you will see in the partial residual plot is the marginal effect of this explanatory variable.

Comment: @JohnK I'm a bit confused. The residuals are calculated from the fit line. So, the residual analysis of a multiple regression gives residuals of the fit line (which includes all predictors) with the observed. Is it safe to say that if the residual plot of the fit line (of multiple predictors) depicted equal variance, that the predictors themselves would also have an equal variance?